# Running multiple steps in sequenze in one parallel block In Jenkinsfile

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I'm trying to optimize my pipeline. I'm using the pipeline to generate and deploy some docs. At the end I clear my document root and write the newly generated docs into the document root. I'm doing this for several stages in parallel.

```
o-----o-----o--+--o--+---+--o--+-----o
               |     |   |     |
               +--o--+   +--o--+
               |     |   |     |
               +--o--+   +--o--+
```

this is the pipeline exerpt for the parallel stages

```
stage("clear nfs directory") {
    steps {
        parallel(
            test: {
                sh "rm -rf /mnt/nfs/test/docs/$pipelineParams.groupname"
                sh "mkdir /mnt/nfs/test/docs/$pipelineParams.groupname"
            },
            rele: {
                sh "rm -rf /mnt/nfs/rele/docs/$pipelineParams.groupname"
                sh "mkdir /mnt/nfs/rele/docs/$pipelineParams.groupname"
            },
            prod: {
                sh "rm -rf /mnt/nfs/prod/docs/$pipelineParams.groupname"
                sh "mkdir /mnt/nfs/prod/docs/$pipelineParams.groupname"
            }
        )
    }
}

stage("copy generated docs to nfs directory") {
    steps {
        parallel(
            test: {
                dir("target/public") {
                    sh "cp -r * /mnt/nfs/test/docs/$pipelineParams.groupname"
                }
            },
            rele: {
                dir("target/public") {
                    sh "cp -r * /mnt/nfs/rele/docs/$pipelineParams.groupname"
                }
            },
            prod: {
                dir("target/public") {
                    sh "cp -r * /mnt/nfs/prod/docs/$pipelineParams.groupname"
                }
            }
        )
    }
}
```

Since clear and write should depend on each other I would like to refactor the pipeline into a more sequential design (running multiple steps in sequence in less parallel steps)

```
o-----o-----o--+--o---o--+-----o
               |         |
               +--o---o--+
               |         |
               +--o---o--+
```

I'm not sure how to run multiple steps in the same parallel block ... can anyone give me a hint? Thanks guys

Comment: does this work for you

Comment: yes, this was exactly what I needed ... thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see below reference which will allow you to run multiple steps in same parallel block.
You would need to use **sequential stages** which will give below output :

```
o-----o-----o--+--o---o--+-----o
               |         |
               +--o---o--+
               |         |
               +--o---o--+
```

```
pipeline {
  agent { label 'master' }
  stages {
    stage('Build and Test') {
      parallel {
        stage("Build and Test Linux") {
          stages {
            stage("Build (Linux)") {
              agent any
              steps {
                echo "Inside for loop 1"
              }
            }
            stage("Test (Linux)") {
              agent any
              steps {
                echo "Inside for loop 2"
              }
            }
          }
        }
        stage("Build and Test Windows") {
          stages {
            stage("Build (Windows)") {
              agent any
              steps {
                echo "Inside for loop 3"
              }
            }
            stage("Test (Windows)") {
              agent any
              steps {
                echo "Inside for loop 4"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

[image]
For more info see:-
https://www.jenkins.io/blog/2018/07/02/whats-new-declarative-piepline-13x-sequential-stages/

Below link gives reference example:
https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-55438